# Unable to quite center list on bottom in Cordova

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am trying to make a bottom navigation bar in Cordova. I created a new app and replaced the `www/index.html` file with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The bulk of the changes being:

```
  <body>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Then to turn the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements in to a navigation bar at the bottom of the phone I tried the following in `www/src/index.html:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:100%;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

The logic being that the `.nav-container` would span the screen of the device. `<ul>` would then bottom align the elements with `align-self: flex-end` and the elements would be centered with `text-align: center`. However, it doesn't look quite centered (ran with `cordova run android`):

[image: Not centered]

Where did I go wrong? How can I get the text to center perfectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UL's by default have a padding-left: 40px; This might be affecting it.